# Integrating private cocoapods repo with OS X Server

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, cocoapods, osx-server

I'm trying to setup Cocoapods with a CI bot via OS X server. I have the following pre-integration trigger:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
cd "$XCS_SOURCE_DIR/myproject"

if [ -e "Pods" ]
then
pod update
else
pod install
fi
```

However some of the pods I have are in a private repo that I've been developing myself and in the output log of a bot integration run, I get:

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Cloning spec repo `my_organization` from `https://github.com/my_organization/CocoapodsPrivateSpecs.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/my_organization/CocoapodsPrivateSpecs.git` named `my_organization`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I verified that there is in fact a private repo on my machine (I was able to push some versions to the github repo). What also confuses me is that the script is trying to add a repo named 'my_organization' but on my machine I named it something else (not sure if that matters).